# Multiple select query with single where clause?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am creating a messaging system. In which there are two type of user admin and user.
Admin can send message to all user and user can send message to admin.
I am trying to fetch,

```
$this->db->select("user_from,count(user_from)as total");
$this->db->from("messages");
$this->db->group_by("user_from");
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result_array();

$this->db->select("*");
$this->db->from("messages");
$this->db->where("user_to","admin");
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result_array();
```

In single both the query work correctly.
I want to include both query in one.
I want to run multiple select query using single where clause which show the last message send by user to admin.
can anyone give me any idea?

[table screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/207u8.png)
[model code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3OOy.png)

Comment: use join with the common column present in both the tables

Comment: how? can you give me any example

Comment: like this :-    SELECT * from messages JOIN(SELECT user_from,COUNT(user_from)as total GROUP BY user_from) WHERE user_to="admin";

Comment: Are you using any framework? If so, which one?

Comment: nope `select * from table1 inner join table2 on table1.id=table2.id`

Comment: yes in codeigniter

Comment: @NishantNair there is a single table messages

Comment: i want functionality like facebook like all user is group by and get last message in messages and when open any message than show full conversation

Comment: On the first query, you are trying to get the count on user_from groupedBy user_from. That should give you a breakdown of the count by user in the messages table. The second query does a select on all fields where the user_to is admin. Both of those queries are achieving different purposes. Why do you want to join the two? If you join the two, you probably won't get all records from the second query because of the groupBy on the first query.

Comment: if a user send two message to admin than i want single row which hold the last message send by user to admin

Comment: Ah ok. You should put that on your question to make it clear that you are only interested in the last message.

Comment: oh sorry now i mention that

Comment: I believe that joining tables is not the answer to your question. Both queries are dealing with the same table: `messages`. Like I mentioned before, those two queries are serving different purposes. One has a where clause and the other does not. On the first query, you may want to change it to: $this->db->select("*,count(user_from)as total"); That should give you all the info per grouped row. The second query is just doing a select on all record sent to admin.

Comment: like facebook in message page all users are group and display last message when you open a particular user message than you see full conversation between you and that user

Comment: i want like that

Comment: Just my $0.02 cents, I believe that restructuring your query alone will not give you want you what you want. There are many ways to achieve what you have described. You might need a mix of front-end and back-end code to get there. I would stop coding and get back to brainstorming again. In a nutshell, return all messages at once. Using some sort of front-end help like jQuery, loop through the code showing just the first 40 messages. when the user clicks the "more" link, show 40 more and so on. If the user opens just the message, jQuery should only show the last message returned (last <div>).

Comment: i don't want like that

Comment: So you may want to do what I proposed earlier in my comments, do a select including *. Please read my message above.

Comment: What you want Last message of every single user to admin?

Comment: yes...i think you got what i want

Comment: I already Submited answer please check that

Comment: it gives error message

Comment: Can you please show me that error?

Comment: i post error on your ans

Answer (score 2):

You can use below query

```
$this->db->select("messages.*,count(messages.user_from) as total");
$this->db->from("messages");
$this->db->group_by("messages.user_from");
$this->db->order_by("messages.user_from","DESC");
$this->db->where("messages.user_to","admin");
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result_array();
```

Comment: Error Number: 1055

Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'dashboardcode.messages.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

SELECT *, count(messages.user_from) as total FROM `messages` WHERE `messages`.`user_to` = 'admin' GROUP BY `messages`.`user_from`

Filename: C:/wamp64/www/dashboard/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691

Comment: can you please display your function for more detail

Comment: this query function of controller

Comment: function get()
            {
                $data['messages'] = $this->message_model->GetUserInbox($this->session->userdata('auser'));
                var_dump($data);
            }

Comment: this is my contoller function

Comment: are you using this session $this->session->userdata(‌​'auser')  in your model function where condition ?

Comment: Can you please display model function

Answer (score 1):

> Your Controller

```
$this->db->where("user_to","admin");
$this->db->group_by("user_from");
$query = $this->db->get('messages');
$data['result'] = $query->result_array(); // Your Result Array
$data['total'] = $query->num_rows(); // total number of records

// You can pass $data in any view file here
```

> Your View

```
print_r($result); // result array
echo $total; // total number of records
```

Comment: this give error  Error Number: 1055

Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'dashboardcode.messages.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE `user_to` = 'admin' GROUP BY `user_from`

Filename: C:/wamp64/www/dashboard/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691

Comment: you have field of named ''user_from" ? share your database table screenshot.

Comment: see screen shot link

Comment: i want functionality like facebook like all user is group by and get last message in messages and when open any message than show full conversation

Comment: after `$query = $this->db->get();` line you put `echo $this->db->last_query();` so you get query and execute this query in phpmyadmin then tell me whats error you get

Comment: i think you made some mistake otherwise it's give perfect result anyway whats us error?

Comment: Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'dashboardcode.messages.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: You only want last message send from user to admin right? in results

Comment: `$this->db->where('user_to','admin');
$this->db->group_by('user_from');
$this->db->order_by('id', 'DESC');
$query = $this->db->get('messages');
`

Comment: put this what you get?

Comment: remove this `$query = $this->db->get('messages');` and check

Comment: if i remove it than i don't mention the table name in this query

Comment: oh sorry it's my mistake `$query = $this->db->get('messages');` this will remain but blank you have to remove

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->db->select("*,user_from,count(user_from)as total");
$this->db->from("messages");    
$this->db->group_by("user_from");
$this->db->where("user_to","admin");
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result_array();
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the last message, use subquery like :

```
select message from messages where id = (select max(id) from messages where user_to = 'admin')
```

Test the query in MySql and if you get the result you want, you can go to codeigniter.

In Codeigniter:

```
 $this->db->select('message')->from('messages');
 $this->db->where('id = (SELECT max(id) FROM messages where user_to = 'admin')', NULL, FALSE);
```

Please correct the use of single quotes in above query as its demo only.

Comment: if i want a particular user last messgae than how i get

Comment: then use where clause in subquery

Comment: how?give me an example

Comment: $this->db->where('id = (SELECT max(id) FROM messages where user_to = 'admin' AND user_from='ram' )', NULL, FALSE);

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->db->select("*,user_from,count(user_from)as total");
$this->db->from("messages");    
$this->db->group_by("user_from");
$this->db->where("user_to","admin");
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result_array();
```

Answer (score 0):

*I have solved my problem.*

> **Modal**

```
function AdminMessages($user)
        {
            $sql = "select * from messages where id in (select max(id) from messages GROUP BY user_from ) AND user_to='".$user."' order by id desc";
            $query = $this->db->query($sql);
            //echo $this->db->last_query();
            return $query->result_array();
        }

        function UserMessages($user)
        {
            $sql = "select * from messages where id in (select max(id) from messages GROUP BY user_to ) AND user_to='".$user."' order by id desc";
            $query = $this->db->query($sql);
            //echo $this->db->last_query();
            return $query->result_array();
        }
```

Comment: hey bro, please check my question https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/189149/codeigniter-expression-1-of-select-list-contains-nonaggregated-column